# Is there a way to texture-paint with symmetry, hiding the symmetrical side but still affecting it?

Tags: texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

*(This question is similar to [Sculpt mode, Symmetry, and the 'H' hotkey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61293/sculpt-mode-symmetry-and-the-h-hotkey), but the workarounds proposed there can't be applied to this case)*

Let’s say I’m texture-painting an A-posed character’s tattoos, with x-axis symmetry on, and that I want to paint on an area such as the inner region of the legs, where one leg keeps getting in the way of the other in the viewport and making painting difficult. I would need some way to invisibilize that leg while still having it receive the brushstrokes symmetrical to the ones I’m applying to the visible one.

Masking doesn’t seem to have any symmetry-preserving option, so, how could I go at this?

On the other hand, is there any addon able to symmetrize one side of an object's texture map while in a Texture Painting Mode's context?

(Editing the texture maps in a paint program to, say, flip a half to cover the other half, isn't practical because of the way the UV mapping is done plus seam issues. Halving the model and using a Mirror Modifier isn't applicable for several reasons, either)

Comment: If Mirror modifier isn't working, I guess I would try a boolean modifier (checked to show in Edit Mode) to hide half the model while I work.

Comment: I've just tried it and, sadly, doesn't work: it correctly hides half of the body while in Texture Paint Mode, but the brushstrokes done while the Modifier is active don't appear in the other side when it is revealed upon deactivating the Modifier. Which kind of makes sense, as its polygons "weren't there" while painting.

(The reason I can't use the Mirror Modifier is that the model has been prepared for rigging already, with vertex groups and weights, and I would lose most of that work if I split it)

Comment: (Same goes for UVs and existing textures. It’s a pre-existing game model, so, rebuilding it isn’t an option)

Comment: Ah that's too bad, I guess being active in edit mode is more literal than I had thought

Comment: I tried using the Mask Modifier with Occlude turned off, and it still seems the projection operation is considered AFTER the mask in view so that the paint only affects the visible geometry.